# iOS Firebase push notification not working but working on pusher

Tags: swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

#### Problem:

Cannot receive push notification for my from firebase given the fact that I was able to receive the device token and firebase token.

Here are my main calls in my `AppDelegate.swift`

`UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()`

This call is successful and I am able to establish connection to APNS because I was able to get my token with this call:

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)`

Also, I know I am connecting to firebase because I am able to get my firebase token with this call:

`func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)`

So I am pretty confident that my code in `AppDelegate.swift` is fine.

#### Here are my steps to configure firebase push notification:

1. Downloaded my google-service.plist file and dragged it into my project
2. Logged into my apple developers account (paid) and created my Key with push notification (copied down the KeyID and along with my teamID or App prefix).
3. Went into my firebase account and uploaded my Key along with my KeyID and TeamID
4. I made sure my app capabilities got the push notification switch to ON
5. Tried sending a test message and app never receives one

My AppDelegate.swift:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        loggingWithSwitftyBeaverConfiguration()
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        // requesting user's permission to accpet push notification
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            
            if granted == true {
                log.debug("User granted push notification")
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            } else {
                log.debug("User did not grant pn")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        log.debug("Device token receiving failed because: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        
        let token = deviceToken.map {String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)}.joined()
        log.debug("Token: \(token)")
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        log.debug("\(remoteMessage.description)")
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        log.debug("Firebase cloud messaging token: \(fcmToken)")
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
    }
    
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
        
        print("push notification received")

    }
    
}
```

Extra information: I was able to receive test notifications by using pusher, just wanted to throw it out there,

Thank you

UPDATE: - working code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var compositionRoot: CompositionRoot?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        window = UIWindow()
        configureCompositionRoot()
        configureFirebase()
        configurePushNotification()
        configureApplicationEntryPoint()
        configureLogging()
        
        return true
    }
    
    func configureCompositionRoot() {
        
        guard let window = window else { return }
        compositionRoot = CompositionRoot(window: window)
    }

    func configureApplicationEntryPoint() {
        
        guard let compositionRoot = compositionRoot else { return }
        compositionRoot.getCoordinator().onStart()
    }
    
    func configureLogging() {
        let console = ConsoleDestination()
        log.addDestination(console)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        
        let token = deviceToken.map {String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)}.joined()
        print("Token: \(token)")
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        
        //Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func configureFirebase() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    func configurePushNotification() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (granted, error) in
            
            if granted == true {
                print("User granted push notification")
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
                
            } else {
                print("User did not grant pn")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    }
    
}
```

Comment: From where you tried to send push notification?

Comment: On firebase cloud messaging

Comment: You can check all the steps agin from here https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/ may be you can find what is missing

Comment: I have also tried this method, not working for me

Comment: Try adding -->  func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { error in
        print(error)
    }
}

Comment: Looks like a deprecated code

Comment: Are you sure your Provisioning Profile's capabilities and your Push Certificates are configured correctly? Because connecting to Firebase is not the same as connecting to APNS. FCM is just a service that is created on top of APNS

Comment: Also you're not calling `Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)` inside your `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method

Comment: Can you show the payload you are sending to FCM???

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue ?

Comment: please see update for my update code that works

Answer (score 1):

Please check your payload. It might be the reason that you are not receiving notifications. 
Your payload should like:

```
{
    "to": "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
    "notification": {
        "body": "great match!",
        "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
        "icon": "myicon"
    },
    "data": {
        "Nick": "Mario",
        "Room": "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
}
```

Having all data under data does not trigger any notification in iOS even though Firebase returns a successful request because the forwarded APNS payload is not correct. Besides the proper way should be to follow the GCM or FCM payload recommendations, which is to use both notification for the notification message and data for custom key/value pairs.

When FCM Send data to APNS it convert it into APNs payload. It set values of notification in aps tag i.e.

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
            "body" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
        }
    },
    "Nick" : "Mario",
    "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for this helpful answer from 18 months ago :) How would you accommodate Android apps which does require the title and body to be in the data for it to show show when the app is in the background?

Answer (score 0):

[Follow the step by step process define here..]

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Answer (score 0):

Another possible lead is to disable Firebase Swizzling as explained here :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: I have read articles about method swizzling and I have zero clue as to what it is doing and how disabling it would solve the problem, please explain, thanks

Comment: Swizzling is an ObjectiveC language feature to replace an implementation of a method with another one on runtime, Firebase uses this for multiple reasons and as we don't have the source code for Firebase SDK we can't tell exactly, hopefully they provide a method to disable it as described in the linked documentation.